# Output only "long pings" / Log connection interruptions

Tags: linux, grep, ping, timestamp

I'm on a connection that sometimes gets interrupted for a while, and I'm trying to determine exactly when using `ping`, which generates output like this:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1196 ttl=64 time=4.64 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1197 ttl=64 time=5.14 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1198 ttl=64 time=4.90 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1199 ttl=64 time=25293 ms < -- interruption
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1200 ttl=64 time=24286 ms      starts here
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1201 ttl=64 time=23278 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1202 ttl=64 time=22270 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1203 ttl=64 time=21262 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1204 ttl=64 time=20254 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1224 ttl=64 time=142 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1225 ttl=64 time=4.87 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1226 ttl=64 time=4.54 ms
```

How can I?

- Output only those lines with a large `time`. Can `grep` do it?
- Add a timestamp to them (I know about the `-D` option of `ping`, but I'd prefer a human-readable stamp)

Comment: what platform is this?  Windows?

Comment: Linux, see tags

Comment: Windows answer removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out this solution with `grep` and `awk` ([ripped from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text), maybe overkill but it works)

```
ping 192.168.0.1 \
| grep -E "time=[0-9]{2}" --line-buffered \
| gawk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of overkill solutions, if you'd still like an answer to your first question (only get lines with a time greater than X), try the following ugly bash-python hybrid script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='\n' read -r -d '' check_ping <<EOF
from sys import stdin
data = reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), stdin.readlines())
time = int(float(data.split("time=")[-1].split(" ")[0].strip()))
if time > $2: print(data)
EOF

ping -c 1 $1 | python -c "${check_ping}"
```

If you put that into a script file, say `test.sh`, you can pass it two parameters: the hostname you want to ping, and the minimum TTL, below which it shouldn't echo the ping output. For example, if you run `tst.sh www.google.com 100` it will only return pings to www.google.com that take more than 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of processing text for this kind of thing although it is the unix-y thing to do.  You might look at perl & Net::Ping.  With it you can define your own timeout and only take action  whenever the ping fails.  More here:

http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Ping.html